# Making Socket.io path work with NGiNX proxy_pass

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io, proxypass

I would like to use NGiNX to proxy pass the following:

```
https://something.com/node.js/foo/bar/baz
```

into this:

```
https://something.com:3000/foo/bar/baz
```

I have successfully done it with the following NGiNX config:

```
location ~ /node.js/(.*) {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1$is_args$args;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

The problem is the following: when I instantiate `socket.io` with the default path, it serves `socket.io.js` here:

```
https://something.com/node.js/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

So far so good, but then this javascript tells the client to make requests here, which fail for obvious reasons:

```
https://something.com/socket.io/...
```

So then I try to instantiate `socket.io` with the `path` option like so:

```
io.listen(server, { path: '/node.js/socket.io'} );
```

But the problem is that now the `socket.io.js` file is hosted here:

```
https://something.com/node.js/node.js/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

Is there a way to tell `socket.io.js` where to host the file `socket.io.js` but still use the given `path`?

What is the normal solution to this `proxy_pass` stuff with `socket.io`??

Answer (score 0):

Well different ways to solve your issue but I would use below one

```
location ~ /node.js/(.*) {
    rewrite "^/node.js/node.js/(.*)$" /node.js/$1 last;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1$is_args$args;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Can you please eplain what it does and how it solves the problem?

Comment: I am just adding a rewrite `rewrite "^/node.js/node.js/(.*)$" /node.js/$1 last;` to fix the double `node.js` url that gets generated when you use `io.listen(server, { path: '/node.js/socket.io'} );`